# compare todays date with calender date (for next seven days only else generate alert )

Tags: javascript, validation

I have to compare todays date with calender date(picking date using date picker ajax).
If date difference is more than 7 days then generate alert.

```
        var mydate = new Date();//Todays date
        var theyear = mydate.getFullYear();
        var themonth = mydate.getMonth() + 1;
        var thetoday = mydate.getDate();

        txtDate.value='04-Jul-2012';//date picker date in this format
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to compare two dates, from strings, begin <= end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336086/javascript-to-compare-two-dates-from-strings-begin-end)

Comment: Not duplicate it s different one

Comment: It's not a different one. It requires exactly the same methods. Then, yes, it's not *character by character* duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var datePicked = '26-Jun-2012';
var datems = Date.parse(datePicked.replace(/-/g, " "));
var dateNow = new Date();
dateNow.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var msDiff = Math.abs(Number(dateNow) - datems);
// 7 Days = 604 800 000 ms
if(msDiff > 604800000) alert("Time difference greater 7 days");
```

Comment: when i get var datePicked = txtDate.value;

Comment: yes, use then var datems = Date.parse(txtDate.value.replace(/-/g, " ")); instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
var mydate = new Date(); //Todays date
txtDate.value='16-Jul-2012'; //date picker date in this format

var newDate = new Date(txtDate.value); //make date object

var difference = Math.ceil((newDate-mydate) / (60*60*24*1000)); //calculate days

if (difference > 7) alert('more than 7 days');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7y9XU/)

Comment: txtDate.value='16-Jul-2012';  which is dynamic date how i do