# How to compare dates - JavaScript/ASP Classic

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript to compare two dates, from strings, begin <= end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336086/javascript-to-compare-two-dates-from-strings-begin-end)

Beginner. I have a HTML form with two date fields the user fills in either manually or by a calendar picker. Start Date and End Date. Before the form can be submitted I want to check to make sure the End Date entered is >= the Start Date entered. Using Dreamweaver. Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Dates comparison:**

```
function compareDates(date1, date2) {
    var delta = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
    if(delta == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

**Dates difference:**

```
var startDate = new Date(),
    endDate,
    delta;

setTimeout(function() {
    endDate = new Date();
    delta = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    alert(delta + ' ms');
}, 1000);​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/bh5Ag/)**

**[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AtST/2/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
    var dt1 = new Date(""+document.getElementById("dt1").value);
    var dt2 = new Date(document.getElementById("dt2").value);
    alert(dt2 > dt1);
}
</script>

<input id="dt1" type="text" value="09/25/2012"/>
<input id="dt2" type="text" value="09/24/2012"/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="test" onclick="test()"/>
```